# Javascript loop inside a loop to Get JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, loops

I want to list Categories and inside each category I want to list subcategories, so I am running loop inside a loop like this, but unfortunately it is returning me like this:

```
Category(Mobile)
Category(Laptop)
Subcategory(Iphone4)
Subcategory(Iphone5)
Subcategory(Iphone6)
Subcategory(dell1)
Subcategory(dell2)
Subcategory(dell3)
```

But what I want is some think like this:

```
Category(Mobile)
Subcategory(Iphone4)
Subcategory(Iphone5)
Subcategory(Iphone6)
Category(Laptop)
Subcategory(dell1)
Subcategory(dell2)
Subcategory(dell3)
```

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
         {
              var url="https://myjson";
              $.getJSON(url,function(result){
                   $.each(result, function(i, field){
                        var categoryId=field.categoryId;
                        var categoryName=field.categoryName;
                        $("#listview").append("<h3>"+ categoryName + "</h3>");
                        $.each(field.subcategories, function(i, row){
                             var id=row.subCategoryId;
                             var subCategoryName=row.subCategoryName;
                             $("#listviewchild").append("<p>"+ subCategoryName + "</p>");
                        });
                   });
              });
         });
```

```html
   <div class="container-fluid">
    
     <div id="listview">
     </div>
     <div id='listviewchild'>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, from your code, your category will always append on the above of your subcategory based on the html that u have.

Here`s the logic that will append as what you need

javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function()
         {
              var url="https://myjson";
              $.getJSON(url,function(result){
                   $.each(result, function(i, field){
                        var categoryId=field.categoryId;
                        var categoryName=field.categoryName;
                        $("#listview").append("<h3>"+ categoryName + "</h3>");
                        $.each(field.subcategories, function(i, row){
                             var id=row.subCategoryId;
                             var subCategoryName=row.subCategoryName;
                             $("#listview").append("<p>"+ subCategoryName + "</p>");
                        });
                   });
              });
         });
```

html

```
   <div class="container-fluid">

     <div id="listview">
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Ohh Thanks alot it worked, I knew that i have a problem with my code but was not able to find correct logic